# search in data array and return matching data

Tags: excel, vba, windows, excel-2010, excel-2007

I have 100 rows with data, example:

```
Led smart TV Noblex 32 '' HD DM32X7000 Android TV
Led smart Philips 32 '' HD 32PHD6825 / 77
```

I need to extract in other columns each data, "brand", "model" "product".
It occurred to me to do it with a data matrix eg.

```
Brand Table: "Phillips", "Noblex", etc (and all other brands)
Table Model: "MD32X7000", "PHD6825 / 77", etc. (and all other models)
```

And I need one or more functions that search the data array inside the cell and extract, if it contains "Phiplips" or "Noblex" for example.
I managed to do something with VBA with this statement with filters "contains":

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$5:$M$700").AutoFilter 3, Array("=*Noblex*"), xlFilterValues
Range("C600").Select
Selection.Offset(0, 9).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp)).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Noblex"

Selection. FillDown
```

But I need it to be with a data matrix since some brands and products can vary and entering VBA each time to change the parameters is very annoying.

This is possible? Or is there some other way?

Thanks, so much

Answer (score 0):

You can use the unique and countif functions for this.
Assuming your source to filter is in col B:

```
=TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(B:B))
```

if you don't need the result in a row remove the transpose.

To count the nr of occurences, assuming the string to search is in F1:

```
=COUNTIF(B:B;F1)
```